# Result prints twice in react when using dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is more of a curiosity question and I feel that it would be useful to know why, but can anyone explain why console.log(recipe) prints twice. When I click Search button the results prints twice in the console. I think i has to do with react re-rendering the component twice, can this be explained in detail.

```
function Search(props) {
    const recipe = useSelector(state => state.recipe)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
    
    console.log(recipe)


    const handleQuery = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Query: ${query}`)
        dispatch(fetchRequest(query))
    }


    return (
        <form className={classes.Search} onSubmit={handleQuery}>
            <input
                className={classes.Search__field}
                placeholder="Search over 1,000,000 recipes..."
                value={query}
                onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button className={[buttonClasses.Btn, "search__btn"].join(' ')} type="submit"
            >
                <svg className={"search__icon"}>
                    <use href={magnifyingGlass + "#icon-magnifying-glass"}></use>
                </svg>
                <span>Search</span>
            </button>

           
        </form>
    );

}


export default Search;
```

Here is where the Search Component is being used

```
import React from 'react';
import Search from './Search/Search';
import classes from './Header.module.css';
import logo from '../../img/logo.png';
import Likes from '../Header/Likes/Likes';

const header = (props) => {


    return (
        <header className={classes.Header}>
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className={classes.Header__logo} />
            <Search />
            <Likes />

        </header>
    )
}



export default header;
```

Header function is then being used in the Layout function which is
in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from './Layout.module.css';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Results from '../Results/Results';


class Layout extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Header />
                <Results />
            </Aux>
        );
    }

}


export default Layout;
```

Here is the redux action

```
import axios from 'axios';

const FETCH_REQUEST = 'FETCH_USERS_REQUEST'

export const fetchRecipe = (recipe) => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_REQUEST,
        payload: recipe
    }
}

export const fetchRequest = (query) => {
    console.log(query)
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios(`https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?q=${query}`)
            .then(response => {
                // console.log(response.data.recipes)
                const recipe = response.data.recipes;
                dispatch(fetchRecipe(recipe));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}
```

[image: reults]

Comment: Please show where you are using the `Search` component in your app.

Comment: can you comment out the dispatch and observe if that logging still prints twice?

Comment: @Menawer when i comment out dispatch, it doesn't do anything because no action is being sent to the redux store. An async api call is being called in the action

Comment: @championq45 so when you click on it, it logs twice, meaning that you have (3 logs in total) or you are referring to the first render log aswell being included in those 2

Comment: Do you have Strict mode enabled? It's enabled by default in new CRA applications and causes double renders.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I do have Strict mode enabled. And I removed it and only renders once. Can you explain why Strict mode does that? Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) will probably explain it better than me - it can be useful to leave on but does sometimes interfere with other packages. It won't be included when you create a production build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I'm not the maximum expert of react, but you could do a test. You know that `useEffect` hook is triggered every time component is re-rendered. So you could put your console.log in useEffect and see if will be logged twice. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(recipe);
})
```

If you got 2 logs, then it means that `Search` component is rendered twice. Otherwise could be something related to reactjs workflow and, as I said, I'm not so expert to explain why is logged twice.

Comment: I did use useEffect and you were right it only printed out once. Also as @lawrence-witt was alluding to, Strict mode was enabled in my app which was causing the component to render twice. Both of these solutions solved the issue.

Comment: Very happy to ear that. Have a nice day :)